# Spree app is empty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I've just followed the spree documentation and installed a new app. The site loads fine, but there are no stylesheets or layout views in my app. All I have is application.html Where is everything else?

Answer (score 0):

I'm new on this too but everything you are looking for is in the gem, you have to download the  source code in order to see what is what you want to override

Comment: Yeah I was thinking that. I thought the source code might get included if i installed a theme but I can't get that to work. So how do I download the source code? Forgive my ignorance :)

Comment: No worries, I'm in the same position as you are, I will recommend to watch the podcast #298 Getting started with Spree with Ryan Bates from railscast.com here is the link :

[link](http://railscasts.com/episodes/298-getting-started-with-spree?view=asciicast)

Comment: Oh, sorry, btw here is the source code for Spree

[github](https://github.com/spree/spree)